# Is there a way to pipe the output of real users into the last command?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to figure out a way to take the output of the list of users and pipe it into the last command directly.

I ran the following command initially and I get the list of all real users.

```
$ getent passwd {1000..60000} | cut -d: -f1 
fly
pig 
cow
```

How do I redirect that output into the last command so that I can display their login times?

Comment: you may try using `xargs` . Example `getent passwd  .....................| cut -d: -f1 |xargs last`

Comment: That worked. Thanks!